# Dynamically generated Bitmap image with aligned data in it

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I'm developing an Winforms application to be used for Led displays. The Led display is size 64x32. I created a test [bitmap image with 4 cells](http://tinypic.com/r/311n9jr/9) size 64x16, so I can output it it to the LED display.

When the user enters 4 numbers in the input form, those Strings are then converted to Bitmap Image and placed inside the cells. I somehow got it to work with this method; It edits the same bitmap image, inserts the numbers, and saves it into a new bmp (or am I wrong?).

```
public static Bitmap Convert_Text_to_Image(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize)
        {

            //creating bitmap image
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("cells.bmp");

            //FromImage method creates a new Graphics from the specified Image.
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
            Font font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
            // Instantiating object of Bitmap image again with the correct size for the text and font.
            SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(txt, font);
            bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, (int)stringSize.Width, (int)stringSize.Height);
            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);




                //Draw Specified text with specified format 
                graphics.DrawString(txt, font, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
                font.Dispose();
                graphics.Flush();
                graphics.Dispose();



            bmp.Save("cells2.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            return bmp;     //return Bitmap Image 

        }
```

The output in the PictureBox is [This](http://tinypic.com/r/2ik4i81/9)

Now I've created myself multiple problems with the alignment, since I just pasted "bmp numbers" directly onto the "bmp cells"... is there a function of "mapping" the numbers correctly inside the cells, depending if its a single-digit or a two-digit number?

I'm pretty certain there's a way easier way to do all of this, maybe with the DataGridView? I only started using C#, any help would be appreciated.

The image "cells.bmp" is just a test image i created in Paint (xd), rather than that, I'm trying to write a function that will create the Bitmap cells through code

```
if (want_x_number_cells) {

      //create bmp with appropriate number of cells

}
```

Comment: Easier way is use four labels. Set autosize to false. You can change text, background color and text color.

Comment: Forgot to thank you, works perfectly:)